# How to put more than 1million ID's using union All

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-performance

I have a comma delimited list of many IDs (database size is very huge here). Sometimes this list can exceed 1000 items, at which point Oracle throws an error. The query is similar to this...

```
select * from table where ID in (1,2,3,4,5,6...,1001,1002,1003...)
```

The above query throws an error saying that expression limit in Oracle is only 1000. So I tried the below query

```
select * from table where ID in (1,2,3,4,5,6...,1000)
union all
select * from table1 where ID in (1001,1002,1003...)
```

The above query works; good. My problem is that I have 1 million ID's which I need to select using the above query. Is it possible to frame this query as 1000's & 1000's using UNION ALL for 1 million IDs? What will the performance be using Oracle 11g?

Is it possible to send multiple statements for 1 million ID's using union All. If so any impact will be there from Database?..

I also checked using OR; but this ends up in failure. I don't have permissions to create a temporary table in my database.

Comment: Are you massively oversimplifying what you want in your `IN` criteria? Otherwise simply state a range such as `WHERE id < 999999` or equivalent rather than fully stating each id.

Comment: Hi YdaetskcoR, thanks for your quick reply. i am not simplifying the query for IN criteria. My Id's may differ it will not be in sequential order.

Comment: Is this question related to Oracle only?  If so, please remove the irrelevant sql-server tag.  With SQL Server, you can pass the list as a table-valued parameter or XML.  I believe XML may be an option for Oracle too.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag. I have removed it. The question is related to oracle only.